# Join two select statements together

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to work out how much we have taken in for entry fees.

I have two separate queries both returning values but i need them be as one instead of two separate queries.

```
SELECT SUM(ENTRY) AS TOTAL1 FROM MONEY

SELECT SUM(ENTRY) AS TOTAL1 FROM MONEY2
```

Comment: Have you tried union?

Comment: i gave it a go but i believe that the values for all the columns must be the same. I have more columns in one then the other. But I am not doubting heather I done this union join correctly.

Comment: You do need the same number of columns (with each column pair being the same datatype), but that is easily fixable by including dummy columns in the select with the fewer columns.  (e.g: select ' ', 0 from dual;)

Comment: I have managed to get the two columns working with union but the values show as 12 and 36. Now I just need to figure out how to add them together

Comment: used the sum function with alias and it works

Comment: @KrisJohnston - No, you don't need the same number of columns - because there is no need to UNION ALL the full tables. All that is needed is to UNION ALL just one column from each table.

Comment: @mathguy I was responding to thewalled100's issue in the comments of: "I have more columns in one then the other.", which, I assumed the "columns" was referring to the columns in the result set, irrespective of the columns in the underlying tables.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use UNION in order to get the statements together. Then used the below to get one number.

```SQL
SELECT SUM(X.TOTAL1) from 
(
 SELECT SUM(ENTRY) AS TOTAL1 FROM MONEY
 UNION
 SELECT SUM(ENTRY) AS TOTAL1 FROM MONEY2
) X;
```

Comment: Careful with `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`; if the two sums just happen to be equal, you will get the wrong answer, because `UNION` removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(entry) as grand_total
from ( select entry from money
       union all
       select entry from money2
     );
```

The point being, you SHOULD use `UNION ALL`; and how many columns each table has is irrelevant, because you don't need to `UNION ALL` the two tables (all columns from each); you only need to `UNION ALL` the `ENTRY` column from the first table and the `ENTRY` column from the second table.